# Verilog output gives 'x'

Tags: verilog

This is a module for a 8 bit shift register using two 4 bit shift registers. 4 bit register modules works fine. (Just testing this for right shift for the moment)

```
module shift_reg_8 (Out,In,shift_left,shift_right,s0,s1,enable,clock);

    output [7:0] Out;
    wire [3:0]Least_Out,Most_Out;                

    input  [7:0] In;                
    wire [3:0]Least_In,Most_In;
    reg temp;

    initial
    temp  = In[4];

    assign {Most_In,Least_In} = In;
    input shift_left,shift_right,enable,s0,s1,clock;        

    shift_reg least_sig_reg(Least_Out,Least_In,shift_left,shift_right,s0,s1,enable,clock);                
    shift_reg most_sig_reg(Most_Out,Most_In,shift_left,shift_right,s0,s1,enable,clock);         

    assign Out = {Most_Out,Least_Out};
    assign Out[3] = temp;

endmodule
```

Here's the test bench.

```
module stimulus;


reg [7:0]INPUT;
reg ENABLE,CLOCK,S0,S1,SL,SR;   

wire [7:0] OUTPUT;  

shift_reg_8 my8shiftreg(OUTPUT,INPUT,SL,SR,S0,S1,ENABLE,CLOCK);       // SL = Shift_Left, SR = Shift_Right, SO,S1 = Controls 

initial
begin

    CLOCK = 1'b0;

    INPUT = 8'b01101110; ENABLE = 1;S0 = 0;S1 = 1;SL = 0;SR = 1;
    #14 $display("Test 1 (Right Shift): INPUT = %b, S1 = %b, S0 = %b, SR = %b, OUTPUT = %b\n",INPUT,S1,S0,SR,OUTPUT);

end

always
#5 CLOCK = ~CLOCK;

    initial
#100 $stop;
```

endmodule

This gives an output like this when simulated.

> Test 1 (Right Shift): INPUT = 01101110, S1 = 1, S0 = 0, SR = 1, OUTPUT = 1011x111

what might be the problem?

Here's the shift_reg code...

```
module shift_reg(Out,In,shift_left,shift_right,s0,s1,enable,clock);

    output [3:0] Out;
    input  [3:0] In;
    input shift_left,shift_right,enable,s0,s1,clock;

    reg [3:0] out_reg;

always @(posedge clock & enable)


begin

if ((s0 == 1'b0) && (s1 == 1'b0))                  // Holding 
    begin                 

    end

else if ((s0 == 1'b1) && (s1 == 1'b0))             // Left Shift
    begin

    out_reg[0] <= shift_left;
    out_reg[1] <= In[0];
    out_reg[2] <= In[1];
    out_reg[3] <= In[2];

    end

else if ((s0 == 1'b0) && (s1 == 1'b1))             // Right Shift
        begin

        out_reg[0] <= In[1];
        out_reg[1] <= In[2];
        out_reg[2] <= In[3];
        out_reg[3] <= shift_right;                        

        end

else if ((s0 == 1'b1) && (s1 == 1'b1))         // Loading 
        begin 

        out_reg <= In;          

        end 

end

assign Out = out_reg;
```

endmodule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning out[3] twice.

```
assign Out = {Most_Out,Least_Out};  // Assigns all 8 bits
assign Out[3] = temp;  //  Assigns bit 3 again.
```

The multiple drivers is causing an unknown state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: It's not an issue with assigning them all one by one.  First just try commenting out the "assign Out[3] = temp" line completely and see if the X resolves.  There could still be more functional problems.

Comment: Just commenting "assign Out[3] = temp"  line gives a valid answer. But ofc it's a wrong answer..so I deleted both lines..and manually assigned all the bits..every bit 'Only' once. No bit get assigned twice..Problem is still there..

Comment: Can you post your shift_reg code.  It's hard to believe that bit[3] would continue to be invalid on your least_sig shift_reg if the same bit is not invalid on your most_sig shift_reg based on your posted code.  Also when you say, "Just commenting 'assign out[3] = temp" gives a valid answer, what do you mean?  What is valid about it?  Does the X resolve?

Comment: Yeah 'x' resolves.. That's what I meant..Shift_reg code is uploaded now.. Take a look..

Comment: Can you state more clearly what the new problem is?  What I can see is that you are combining two x4 shift registers and you are trying to hide that fact from the top level which looks like a x8 shift reg.  In one x8, there can only be one shift left and one shift right, which you have.  BUT... you are using that shift left and shift right on both the most and least shift reg's.  Your shift left can go to one of those device, and the shift_right can go to the other.  Internally, you need cross connect the outs to the unused shift to cross the data from one to the other on a shift operation.

Comment: yeah I was trying to store the bit that should be passed to the least register and assigned it later at the end...Doesn't work like that it seems..I figured it out tho... I just connected in[4] with a temp wire and passed that to the least register as an argument instead of shift_right argument.. did the job... Thanks for your time man..Appreciate it :)